# Proof that $x_1=x_2$ maximizes $f(x_1)+f(x_2)$, when its derivatives are unequal until $x_1=x_2$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

Given some function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. define $g: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ as

$$g(x_1,x_2)=f(x_1)+f(x_2)$$

Assume that $f$ is decreasing in argument. Define $X$ as the sum of $x_1+x_2$. $X$ is assumed to be some finite constant. Hence, whenever $x_1$ increases, the value of $x_2$ decreases by the same amount. Claim: $g(x_1,x_2)$ is maximized when $x_1=x_2$. I argue this using the following fact (that I know independently to be true):

$$\frac{\partial f(x_1)}{\partial x_1}>\frac{\partial f(x_2)}{\partial x_2} \iff f(x_1)>f(x_2).$$

Which (I believe) states that increasing $x_1$ and decreasing $x_2$ increases  $g(x_1,x_2)$, whenever $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$. Note that $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$ $\iff$ $x_1< x_2$ since $f$ is decreasing in its argument. Hence, $g(x_1,x_2)$ can be increased by transferring value from $x_2$ to $x_1$ until $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Conversely, I also know that

$$\frac{\partial f(x_1)}{\partial x_1}<\frac{\partial f(x_2)}{\partial x_2} \iff f(x_1)<f(x_2).$$

And we can increase $g$ by transferring value from $x_1$ to $x_2$ whenever $x_1>x_2$. Since this holds everywhere for $g(x_1,x_2)$ whenever $x_1 \neq x_2$ we can increase $g$ by transferring value between $x_1$ and $x_2$. Hence $g$ is maximized when $x_1=x_2$. Does this argument work?

Comment: Huh? You mean $f'(x_1) >f'(x_2)$?

Comment: No I mean $f(x_1)> f(x_2)$. I will try clarify this in my question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: While you're at it clarify your assumptions. You say $f$ is decreasing in the arguments $x_1$ and $x_2$... $f$ only has one argument . Things might be simplified if you just write $x_2= X-x_1$ everywhere.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the simplest argument is that $$\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)+f(X-x)) = f'(x)-f'(X-x)$$ which implies $x=X/2$ is a critical pt. Other assumptions might be needed to make sure it's a min/max and I'm a little unclear on your assumptions so not sure if it's pinned down or not.

Comment: 'decreaing' doesn't necessarily mean $\frac{\partial f(x_1)}{\partial x_1}>\frac{\partial f(x_2)}{\partial x_2} \iff f(x_1)>f(x_2)$

Comment: That's a separate assumption. Sorry if that was not more clear. I will try clarify this in the question.

Answer (score -1):

A thought rather than an answer:

This looks as if it's closely related to the standard ideas of an optimum on the production-possibility curve in Economics. The proofs usually given in textbooks implicitly assume that the PP curve is convex, so that there's a unique maximum. You may be making a similar assumption here. As written, I don't actually believe the claim you're trying to prove, although I confess I haven't read it carefully -- it's too muddled for my taste.